# position: fixed only on height

Tags: css, css-position

I'm working on this page: http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/4RzyG/embedded/result/

code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/4RzyG/

It works fine in Safari/Firefox/Chrome and other decent browsers. However, when opening it with Safari Mobile and pinching (zomming in) something strange happens.

As you can see, text fades away at the bottom of the page: this is done thanks to a png image with transparency applied at the bottom of the central div. They are both made to occupy the same space and handle window resizing but not Safari Mobile zooming.

This makes sense if you read the code: the bottom gradient (the png image) uses `position: fixed` to stay always at the center of the page but, as soon as you "pinch in" with Safari Mobile, it will always remains in the center.

I'd like the position to be fixed only for the height of the element (otherwise when scrolling the png image will detach from the bottom) but not for the width. Is this possible? How would you change the code to make it work on iOs?

This is the css code which control the text fade out by placing the png image

```
.bottom_fade_center {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;

            width: 80%;
            left: 10%;

            background: url("bottom-fade.png");
            background-repeat:repeat-x;
            height: 400px;
            pointer-events:none;
            z-index: 3;

            }
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you strip the example code down to just the relevant part? There's so much code there (the entire HTML page, reset rules, everything!), it's incredibly hard to work out where the pertinent problem is.

Comment: posted! Thanks for pointing out, I totally forgot to post the code...

Comment: I'm sorry not for providing you a corrected code, but I can give some hints. -- http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed As you see, {postion:fixed} is not perfect in iOS. http://igstudio.blogspot.com/2012/09/positionfixed-in-ios-6.html I came across this guy who suggests how to fix this issue.

Comment: Might position absolute work instead? Might need to make a container or two for it to get it where you want. I realize this is a fundamental change but you might settle for it.

Comment: I can't. If I use absolute, the background would remain where it is as I scroll the page and I don't want this to happen. I want it to stay sticked to the bottom of the window.