# Smooth transition of header to a floating header

Tags: jquery, css

For the [website I'm working on](http://www.shanycosmetics.com.php54-1.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/), I have written the following JQuery to convert the header to a floating header when people scroll so the header always remains visible. I was just wondering if anybody knows about a way to make this transition a little smoother. Right now it happens very quickly and not very smooth.

**JQuery**:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var header = $("#header");
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (top > 125) {
        header.addClass('fixed-header');
    }
    else{
        header.removeClass('fixed-header');
    }
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.fixed-header{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: Try hiding header and then after adding class fixed-header, do a fadeIn or something

Comment: That's a good approach; however, I just want that smooth transition to happen the very first time you move away from the regular header. When you keep scrolling, I want the header to stay at top without any flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need the transition?

Just keep the header always in floating mode and you won't even need javascript to switch between one mode and the other. As the user is on top of the page the header will be on top too. Just use `position: fixed`.

Comment: Btw, you must be VERY careful. Position: fixed is a pain in the arse when navigating with safari mobile. Check out which problem I had with a footer on my iPad browser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967641/position-fixed-only-on-height

Comment: I have created a separate website for mobiles. Won't be using fixed header on mobile and tablets. Thanks